# Zend Form Validation not working

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I have created a zend form. I have added some elements. I have put validate attribute in all elements but validation in not working out. 
Here is my code

```
  /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
    $this->setMethod('post');
   $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
       'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            'EmailAddress',
        )
    ));
   // Add the comment element
    $this->addElement('textarea', 'comment', array(
       // 'label'      => 'Please Comment:',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20))
            )
    ));

    // Add a captcha
    $this->addElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
        //'label'      => 'Please enter the 5 letters displayed below:',
        'required'   => true,
        'captcha'    => array(
            'captcha' => 'Figlet',
            'wordLen' => 5,
            'timeout' => 300
        )
    ));

    // Add the submit button
    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
       'ignore'   => true,
        'label'    => 'Sign Guestbook',
    ));

    // And finally add some CSRF protection
    $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
        'ignore' => true,
    ));
```

Not even a single validation in working out. On my view I just `echo` the form object. Would any body tell me where Am I Wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure... Are you calling `$form->isValid()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @dinopmi `$form->isValid` will not be used for server side validation? OK also tell me that the validation code above will be used for server side validation or client side validation

Comment: nevermind, i just repeat what dinopmi said in his answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Zend_Form` is supposed to validate your input in the server side. To use it, you need to send the data to the server somehow, and then call `$form->isValid($data)`.

- The simple way would be just to submit the form, and validate the data in your action, there are some good tutorials about it, for instance this one: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ .
- If you want to leverage the validators but still want to get some validation feedback before submitting the form, you can also send the data through Ajax. The following tutorial tells you a nice way to do it using jQuery: http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/ . I followed it and it was quite good.

In any case, keep in mind that the validation is always run in the server side.

Hope that helps,